# Извлечь файлы внутри папки которая в zip?

Tags: php, zip

Есть архив с содержимым

```
archive.zip -> folder -> file1
                      -> file2
                      -> file3
```

Если следовать документации то мы получим следующее:

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive;

  $extract = $zip->open('archive.zip');

  if ($extract === TRUE) {
   $zip->extractTo('root_dir');


   $zip->close();
   echo 'Успех';

  } else {
         echo 'ошибка';
  }
```

Оно разархивирует вместе с папкой folder, но мне нужно извлечь все что находиться внутри folder но саму папку не сохранять. Все доку прочитал и не нашел, значит ли что это не возможно ?

Каким образом я могу извлечь только файлы, которые находятся внутри folder ?

Comment: после извлечения скопируйте файлы из folder куда надо, а folder удалите

Comment: Название папки известно и постоянно? Если так, то смотрите пример с англоязычного [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102379/extract-folder-content-using-ziparchive)